# Nesting if statements only trigger the top if statement inside - python 3.5.2

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

So here is my program. The whole premise of it is that it's supposed to be a story made by the input and adding them to strings:

```
from random import *

pribeh = str(input("Vyber si typ príbehu.\n\n A - Invázia\n B - Návšteva\n C - Obed\n "))

if pribeh == "A" or "a":

    meno1 = str(input("Zadaj meno\n"))
    pribehA1 = ("Jedného dna som stanoval s mojim kamarátom " + meno1 + ".")
    farba1 = str(input("Zadaj farbu (v dátive, ženský rod)\n"))
    pribehA2 = ("Zrazu sme videli svetlo " + farba1 + " farby.")
    velkost1 = str(input("Zadaj velkost\n (VELKÁ(A), ALEBO MALÁ?(B), v inštrumentáli, ženský rod)\n"))

    if velkost1 == "A" or "a":
        velkost1 = 50
        pribehA3 = ("Zo svetla sa vynorila postava s velkou hlavou.")
    elif velkost1 == "b" or "B":
        velkost1 = 10
        pribehA3 = ("Zo svetla sa vynorila postava s malou hlavou.")
    sloveso1 = str(input("Vyber sloveso\n (C) - utekat\n (D) - schovat\n"))

    if sloveso1 == "A" or "a":
                    pribehA4 = ("Cudný tvor nás vydesil, tak sme sa rozhodli utekat.")
                    lokalita1 = str(input("Zadaj miesto (v akuzatíve)\n"))
                    pribehA5 = ("Utiekli sme na " + lokalita1 + ".")
    elif sloveso1 == "B" or "b":
                    pribehA4 = ("Cudný tvor nás vydesil, tak sme sa rozhodli schovat.")
                    lokalita1 = str(input("Zadaj miesto (v akuzatíve\n)"))
                    pribehA5 = ("Po schovávani sme už tvora nevideli. Všetko sme zbalili a odišli na " + lokalita1 + ".\n")

    print(pribehA1)
    print(pribehA2)
    print(pribehA3)
    print(pribehA4)
    print(pribehA5)
    print("Nakoniec som sa zobudil sám doma. Teraz sa seba pýtam, je to co sa stalo realitou, alebo len bujný sen?")

else:

    mesto = str(input("Zadaj mesto (lokál)\n"))
    podm1 = str(input("Zadaj podstatné meno\n"))
    podm2 = str(input("Zadaj podstatné meno\n"))
    hobby = str(input("Zadaj hobby\n"))
    pridm = str(input("Zadaj prídavné meno\n"))

    print("Na výlete v " + mesto + "som navštívil môjho strýka.")
    print("Strýko mal v jeho dome mnoho ozdôb ako napríklad "+ podm1 +".")
    print("Casto krát mi hovoril rady z jeho životnej skúsenosti ako napríklad, že nemám jest "+ podm2+".")
    print("Jeho oblubene hobby je " + hobby + "." )
    print("Osobne si myslím, že môj strýko je velmi" + pridm +"clovek.")
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does `velkost1 == "A" or "a"` This will always be true. Input is already a string and you can reduce your conditions to not check capital and lowercase.

Comment: What should I replace it with? Any good alternative?

Comment: @Mckay `if pribeh.lower() == "a": ...` for case-insensitive matches, `if pribeh in ("a", "A"): ...` for multiple matches. Same goes for all your other conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much I'm so happy now. I love this website already.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional alternatives in your case:

```
velkost1 == "A" or velkost1 == "a"
velkost1 in ["A", "a"]
velkost1.lower() == "a"
velkost1.upper() == "A"
```

In your case `velkost1 == "A" or "a"`:

- 1st condition: `velkost1 == "A"` can be `True` or `False` depending upon the value of  `velkost1`
- 2nd condition: `"a"` which will always be `True`

because of `or` operation between these 2 conditions, the output will always be `True`.

**Quit or Continue**

```
pribeh = str(input("Vyber si typ príbehu.\n\n A - Invázia\n B - Návšteva\n C - Obed\n "))
while pribeh.lower() in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    if pribeh == "A" or "a":
        # do something
    else:
        # do something
    pribeh = str(input("Vyber si typ príbehu.\n\n A - Invázia\n B - Návšteva\n C - Obed\n "))
```

Now the program will only execute, if user enters any letter than 'a', 'b' or 'c' and at the end of while loop we are again taking user input, basically from there he can continue by entering 'a', 'b' or 'c' and can quit by entering any other character.

Comment: Since he's a beginner, I recommend making those changes and showing some corrected code.

Comment: thought the same, but as he's a beginner that's why I posted the error and what can be the possible alternatives to solve.

Comment: It's all working now. I just need to make an input whether the person wants to quit, or restart the whole thing completely, if it's possible

Comment: check my edit, by this way, you will be able to implement quit/continue functionality. If this solves your purpose please do mark it as the correct answer.